# Making sure TCP port is available for listen in the context of automated tests?

Tags: c#, windows, tcp

We have some integration tests that will start an HTTP server process, verify calls, stop (or kill) server, rinse & repeat.

The whole point of these tests is that they run end-to-end over the full client-tcp-http-server stack. And we have to restart the server because we need to test multiple configuration options.

Now, the problem when running these automatically on Windows is that sometimes (1/10? 1/20? ...) re-starting the server will fail with

```
System.ServiceModel.AddressAlreadyInUseException: Für den IP-Endpunkt 0.0.0.0:59951 ist bereits ein Listener vorhanden.
```

because the port is not available for listen (yet?).

We had some success in the past by adding multi-second delays before starting the server again, but this seems so clunky.

Please note that the server is not always gracefully shut down, either because the test case requires forceful termination or because its just easier from the driver script to just TerminateProcess the server.
Anyhow - since the process "owning" the socket is dead, it will be available shortly after process end, but its unclear how long this can take or how to test it.

- How can the script that will start the server make sure iff the endpoint that the server is going to bind to is available?
- Alternatively: Is there a useful strategy for the server code to try to recover/retry if it cannot bind to an endpoint?
- Ifff we were to add a delay, how long should this be?

Comment: Looks like it's not closing the listener port properly. Check for missing `using`

Comment: @Charlieface - well yes, no it's not closing the listener port at al, because in some cases for some tests the server is forcefully terminated. I'll add as much to the question, thanks for raising this.

Comment: Maybe lower the `IdleConnection` timer